# Eliminating Span Elements in a nested TD using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, css, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to webscraping, so I wrote a small little script to extract player scores from this site: http://fold.it/portal/players

Here's the code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.fold.it/portal/players").read()

for row in soup('tr', {'class':'even'}):
  rank = row('td')[0].string
  td2 = row('td')[1]
  for name in td2('a'):
     user = name.text
  score = row('td')[2].string

print rank, user, score
```

Now, this works pretty well except the user also has the two other scores in their name as well.  Looking at the html, it seems there are two span elements after the a href.
[image: Sample output]

My first thought was to split 'user' on white space, but some names have spaces in them, so that didn't work.  I also thought about looking for numeric, but some users have numeric names as well.

I figure eliminating the span is my best option.  However, I'm not sure what the best way to parse them out would be.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scores are in the separate `span` tags - use it:

```
for row in soup('tr', {'class': 'even'}):
    cells = row('td')
    rank = cells[0].string

    # finding the first text node - this is our name
    name = cells[1].a.find(text=True).strip()

    # ranks are in two separate `span` tags
    rank1, rank2 = cells[1].find_all("span")

    print name, rank1.text, rank2.text
```

Prints:

```
Galaxie 1 3
smilingone 2 35
LociOiling 3 9
Desnouck Maarten 4 153
...
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked perfectly!